# Showing stars for rating

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

Hey all i have problem with rating project. I am sending comment to api and have number(rating) back and i want to show stars instead number. i will show my jquery code.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click', '#calculateProductRate', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            calculateProductRate();

        });
        let ratingCalc = function(){
            let star = $(".score").html();
            let rating1= $('#star1');
            let rating2= $('#star2');
            let rating3= $('#star3');
            let rating4= $('#star4');
            let rating5= $('#star5');

            if(star == 1){
                rating2.css("display", "none");
                rating3.css("display", "none");
                rating4.css("display", "none");
                rating5.css("display", "none");
            }
            else if(star == 2){
                rating3.css("display", "none");
                rating4.css("display", "none");
                rating5.css("display", "none");
            }
            else  if(star == 3){
                rating4.css("display", "none");
                rating5.css("display", "none");
            }
            else if(star == 4){
                rating5.css("display", "none");
            }
            else if(star == 5){
            }

            console.log(star);
        }
        let calculateProductRate = function(){
            let text = $('textarea[name="aiTool"]').val();
                    ratingCalc();
            $.get( "{{ route('calculate-rate') }}", { text: text } )
                .done(function(data) {
                    $('#score').text(data);
            });
        }
    });
```

html

```
<section class="ai-tool paddinglr">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="ai-text">
                <h1> Try our AI tool</h1>
                <p>
                    We have developed a tool that converts words into actual rating number. That number can be presented as any graphic element you want. It is open to test it right here and right now. Multiple times.
                    We would be more than happy to hear a feedback from you. Feel free to contact us at hello@thevegansheep.com
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="ai-form w-100">
            <div class="col-12 ">
                            <h4 for="aiTool">Try our Ai tool</h4>
                            <textarea name="aiTool" class="w-100" cols="30" width='100%' rows="5" placeholder="We have developed a tool that converts words into actual rate number. That number can be translated to icon,graphic or what ever you want.You can try it right here,right now."></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="ai-btn w-100">
            <div class="col-12">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-gold btn-ai mt-4 px-4" id="calculateProductRate">Convert to rate</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
                <span id="score" class="score">3</span>
            <div class="rating m-auto">
                <div class="star mt-4">
                    <img src="./assets/images/star.png" id="star1" class="star1" alt="">
                    <img src="./assets/images/star.png" id="star2" class="star2" alt="">
                    <img src="./assets/images/star.png" id="star3"  class="star3" alt="">
                    <img src="./assets/images/star.png" id="star4" class="star4" alt="">
                    <img src="./assets/images/star.png" id="star5" class="star5" alt="">
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>
</section>
```

The problem is, when i caluclte rating , i have to click twice to have stars(but rating show on first click) and it just works for 2 times for showing stars.

Comment: Please include all relevant code, like html and css

Comment: Posting the HTML code can help people reproduce the issue you are facing, and understand the problem (you can use the Javascript/HTML/CSS code snippet in your editor) which enables them to help you more easily.

Comment: @Silidrone while you are correct that posting an reproduceable example of the problem will be good, you should ask them to use Stack Overflows snippet tool (Edit question and use `<>`), then the example will always be avaliable.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Yeah I just remembered that and edited my comment before you commented :D

Comment: just posted html code

Comment: @AmirAlibašić You can short down most of your code inside `ratingCalc` by using `$("img[id^=star]").hide();$("img[id^=star]:lt("+star+")").show();`

Comment: @AmirAlibašić Also when I test your code it works fine on the first click

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen khmm , and it works after more than 2 number change ?

Comment: @AmirAlibašić what makes you believe it stops working?

Comment: `console.log` data which you set `$('#score').text(data);` is it number only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're calling `ratingCalc()` before getting the number of starts. You should have that instead:

```js
let calculateProductRate = function(){
   let text = $('textarea[name="aiTool"]').val();
   $.get( "{{ route('calculate-rate') }}", { text: text } )
      .done(function(data) {
           $('#score').text(data);
           ratingCalc();
      });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Call your `ratingCalc(data)` method by passing data inside
`.done` method. Remove the first line inside `ratingCalc` method.

> **Note:** Use `const` instead of `let` while defining method
> (Recommended), because you will not be reassigning the variable with
> other definition.

```
const ratingCalc = function (star) {
  // let star = $(".score").html(); // remove this line
  let rating1 = $('#star1');
  let rating2 = $('#star2');
  // your code....
}

const calculateProductRate = function () {
  let text = $('textarea[name="aiTool"]').val();
  $.get("{{ route('calculate-rate') }}", { text: text })
    .done(function (data) {
      $('#score').text(data);
      ratingCalc(data);
    });
}
```